# Automatically creating missing join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Lately I've grown weary of littering my `app/models` directory with pointless boilerplate models such as:

- Join models that always contain a couple `belongs_to`s and nothing else.
- Status log models that just `include SomeConcern` and make a couple macro calls.
- Revision tracking models that again, just include a concern and call a macro.

These models only exist to support `has_many` and `has_many ... through:` associations.

Adding model concerns that generate these models as needed clears simplifies the `app/models` directory. So instead of:

```
has_many :model_things
has_many :things, through: :model_things
```

and a trivial `app/models/model_thing.rb` that says:

```
class ModelThing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

I can have a `ThingSupport` concern with a `has_things` macro that:

1. Creates the `has_many :model_things` association based on the class name and some options to `has_things`.
2. Creates the `has_many :things, through: :model_things` association.
3. Find or create the `Model::Thing` (see below for why this name is used) class with a call like:

   ```
    ModuleUtil.find_or_create(join_model_name) do
     Class.new(ApplicationRecord) do
       # Set the table name, call belongs_to as needed, call concern methods, ...
     end
   end
   ```

   where `ModuleUtil.find_or_create` is a simple method that uses `String#constantize` to find the desired module (if it exists) or create it using the block and `Object#const_set` if it can't be found.

All the model and association names can be built using the usual Rails conventions from the caller's class name and some options to `has_things` for special cases.

The question is am I playing with fire here? What can go wrong with this sort of chicanery?

One problem that I've already come across is that the model classes that are generated don't exist on their own so they cannot be directly referenced from an ActiveJob (such as a `deliver_later` mailer). For example, if loading `Model` creates the `ModelThing` association model then you can't reference a `ModelThing` in a mailer argument because ActiveJob won't know that you have to load the `Model` class before `ModelThing` exists. However, this can be solved by using `Model::Thing` instead so that `constantize` will look for `Model` (and find it in `app/models/model.rb`) before trying to find `Model::Thing` (which will exist because `constantize` will have just loaded `Model` which creates `Model::Thing`). Am I missing something else?

Comment: wow, a gold `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails` member asking a question 

Comment: Is there a reason [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) doesn't work here? (I'm assuming there is, and I just missed it)

Comment: "model classes that are generated don't exist on their own" you could use a file in `initializers` to handle this part. Also have you considered looking into the extend option of a `has_many` relationship? Seems like you could probably make this logic modular and cross class applicable

Comment: @engineersmnky Or just use `Model::Thing` so that `'Model::Thing'.constantize` will `'Model'.constantize` (thus creating `Model::Thing`) along the way. I prefer the namespacing over making things even more diffuse with an initializer. And yes, I do use the extension blocks in combination with all this, sometimes I'll capture the extension block in a module that can be mixed into a generated class.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner HABTM tends to be cumbersome to deal with, hence the existence of has-many-through. I'm not sure how easy it is to add extra information to the join table with HABTM.

Comment: @muistooshort `extend` can take a complete module as an argument that's why I suggested it

Comment: @engineersmnky I tend to use the extension block (i.e. `has_many :things do ... end`), convert that to a module, and mix it into something. Seems simpler to me when there are only a couple knobs to frobnicate. That said, creating a module from various bits and pieces and then using `extend:` to mash it into the association is a nice option to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea if I'm following you or not. So, if this is way off target, please say so and I'll delete.

Focusing in on the join model bit, I also got tired of that flim flam. So, I created a model like:

```
module ActsAsHaving
  class HasA < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :haser_type, :haser_id, :hased_type, :hased_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :hased, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :haser, polymorphic: true

    acts_as_taggable

    def haser=(thing)
      self.haser_type = thing.class.name
      self.haser_id   = thing.id
    end

    def haser
      haser_type.constantize.find_by(id: haser_id)
    end

    def hased=(thing)
      self.hased_type = thing.class.name
      self.hased_id   = thing.id
    end

    def hased
      hased_type.constantize.find_by(id: hased_id)
    end

  end
end
```

I didn't use the built-in accessors and validations because I sometimes use this to join non-AR records (which I grab from remote API services some of which belong to me and some of which don't but that's a longer story).

Anyway, I then wrote an `acts_as_having` macro that let me do stuff like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_having :health_events, class_name: "Foo::Event", tag_with: "health_event", remote: true
  acts_as_having :program_events, class_name: "Foo::Event", tag_with: "program_event", remote: true
  acts_as_having :email_addresses, :phone_numbers, :physical_addresses

end
```

Which gives me stuff like:

```
@person.email_addresses
@person.email_addresses << @email_address 
etc...
```

I can do the inverse like:

```
class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_had_by :person

end
```

Which gives me stuff like:

```
@email_address.person
etc...
```

Then, I wrapped all that junk up into a gem. Now I rarely create join models unless they have some specific requirements that I can't shoe horn into my `acts_as_having` bit.

Anyway, I don't know if it's playing with fire or not. I don't even know if I'm making sense or addressing your concept. But, I started my gem about three years ago and I haven't regretted it. So, there's that.

Comment: You're definitely playing around in the same area that I am so you're making sense. I've also been using my `ModuleUtil.find_or_create` chicanery to avoid the unpleasantness that polymorphic associations do in the database (tying your database to a single application is a bit of an abomination in my mind so things like polymorphic association and STI are rarely applicable). In my case, the `Foo::Event` class could be generated by `acts_as_having`. The real underlying idea is to not write boilerplate by hand.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Oh that there were a way to have a longer, more detailed discussion. SO Q&A doesn't quite do it. Would love to hear more.